# Coin probability problem - short method

Tags: probability

Let we have  a coin with  probability to get  head  is $0.5$. With 10 successive trials we need to get the probability at least 6 head. THis mean 5 head, 4 head also included Then.

> Can I use this theorem?:
>
> $nCk$ $\times$ $p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$
>
> $n= 10, k= 6,$.

I want a  method which may take very short time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you could use a shortcut.  The chances of at least 6 heads is the same as the probability of getting at least 6 tails due to the symmetry in the problem.  The only other possibility is getting exactly 5 heads.

Thus the desired probability $= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(1- \dfrac{\binom{10}{5}}{2^{10}}\right) = \dfrac{193}{512} \sim 37.7\%$

Comment: WHy the $\frac{1}{2}$ arises? can you write the formula details

Comment: Breaking it up, the chance of getting exactly 5 heads is by the formula you referred to, $q = \operatorname{C}(10, 5) (0.5)^5(0.5)^5 = \dfrac{\operatorname{C}(10, 5)}{2^{10}}$.  Now $1-q$ is the probability of having either at least 6 heads, or at least 6 tails, and these probabilities are identical by symmetry.  Hence each probability $=\frac{1}{2}(1-q)$, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

We oberve that $$\mathrm{Pr}[\text{at least } 6 \text{ heads}]=\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } 6 \text{ heads}]+\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } 7 \text{ heads}]+\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } 8 \text{ heads}]+\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } 9 \text{ heads}]+\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } 10 \text{ heads}]$$ since the events "exactly $i$ heads" and "exactly $j$ heads" are [mutually exclusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_exclusive_events) when $i \neq j$.

The formula you mention is for $$\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } k \text{ heads}]=\binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ with $n$ trials.  In this case, we have $n=10$ and $p=0.5$.

So, yes, it can be used (once for each of the 5 terms above).

Comment: So if the question says at least 6 heads we can not use the formula I wrote??

Comment: That formula is for *exactly* 6 heads.  If we're after *at least* 6 heads, then we need to account for the possibilities of 6 heads, 7 heads, and so on, up to 10 heads, also.